# Is there a way to override production.rb? ( do initializers run after the config/environments folder )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to set `config.public_file_server.headers` on many different apps (using a gem), some of which may already have this setting in `production.rb`. My initial thought is that I may be able to do it in a custom initializer, however I am unsure of whether or not initializers have the ability to overwrite configuration settings in this file. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Rails will load `load_environment_config` before `load_config_initializers`. You can find the initializer order here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers . You should be able to create an initializer to override the loaded rails config.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like initializers run after environment.rb as well as the specific environment files.

```
1. config/preinitializer.rb
2. config/environment.rb
3. config/environments/#{RAILS_ENV}.rb
4. plugin initialization
5. gem initialization
6. config/initializer/*.rb
7. all after_initialize blocks, in the order they were defined in (so same order as above)
8. any junk left below the Rails::Initializer.run call/block in environment.rb
```

source: http://willbryant.net/rails_initialization_and_configuration_order